# What patent attorney did james dyson use on his bagless vaccum patent?

Tags: patentability

What patent attorney did James Dyson use on his bagless vacuum patent?

Answer (score 1):

US patents at least provide the attorney's name right on the front page. I found [US4593429A](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/141-306-660-645-862) which I think is the US version of the patent you are referring to. You can see from there that the "Attorney, Agent or Firm" is listed as Ian C. McLeod.